# Normal distribution of errors

Tags: regression, overfitting, bayes-error

I'm trying to project lifetime of customers in my company, based on various parameters
I've reached a 64% correlation so far, between the valid and prediction data
I'm using light GBM regressor

I did a sanity check on my prediction data and calculated the series of errors: Y_valid - pred
The error distribution is a classic normal one!

If I can project the error based on it's distribution, can I normalize (or rather "un-normalize") the prediction, and improve the accuaracy of my prediction ?

Is there a way to set an "error offset" with the regressor in the parameters ?